# Is an interior disconnect required for an AC unit?

Tags: electrical, hvac

I'm trying to understand why my outside AC unit has 2 shutoff breakers (not including the main panel). There is a breaker installed on the INSIDE basement wall of the house. Outside there is another shutoff breaker right at the AC unit.

I know current codes state that a shutoff breaker must basically be 'within sight' of the unit. I'm thinking the inside breaker was there originally and later someone added the outside breaker to bring it up to code but was lazy and didn't touch the inside breaker.

**Main question**: I want to remove the inside redundant breaker and just run the cable directly to the outside breaker. The two breakers are only about 30 inches away from each other and I know I have enough slack to make the connection on the existing cable. I can't see any flaw in this logic. Anyone else?

[image: Inside Breaker]

[image: Inside Breaker 2]

[image: Outside Breaker]

Comment: Outside for code, indoor for convenience but if it has a dedicated HACR breaker in the panel then the indoor one is redundant. The indoor one may have been installed so that people unfamiliar with the panel can easily shut off the A/C unit.

Comment: The main panel is a Square D QO with a 2 pole 40 amp breaker for the AC unit. I believe this means it's HACR listed. Convenience be damned. This thing on the wall has been an eye sore for years and now that we're remodeling the basement I want it gone! =). Waiting for more responses and research. Thanks.

Comment: "I believe" isn't good enough when it comes to electrical. I believe the drywall is flat enough is OKAY but there's a lot more at stake when talking about electrical. Do you have this product? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-QO-40-Amp-2-Pole-Circuit-Breaker-QO240CP/100075398

Comment: Looks like you might be safe per https://ckm-content.se.com/ckmContent/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/0691H00000EFWqIQAX . Does your breaker have a UL489 somewhere on it? Per https://www.se.com/us/en/faqs/FA230479/

Comment: Understood. I was being a little facetious. That is exactly the breaker installed. I can't see the UL code on it, since it's installed and I don't want to pull it out right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need the redundant inside disconnect but it may be a fused unit.
I would check for fuses if you have an old panel your breakers may not be HACR listed and the fuses meet that requirement. If that case is rated 3r it could go outside and still meet code requirements but it looks like an inside model but I am on my phone so look if the label in side states 3R if it has fuses and you will be good to eliminate the inside one.

Comment: No fuses on inside breaker (see updated pic). The main panel is a Square D QO with a standard 2 pole 40 amp breaker for the AC unit. From limited searching it seems the SquareD QO breakers are HACR listed?

Comment: Oh you are good to go (one of the things I love about QO panels) Rip er out!

Comment: Follow-up: I removed the interior panel and ran the circuit to the exterior cutoff. Everything is good. No issues. I'm glad to get that ugly panel off the wall.

Answer (score 2):

YIKES!!! The ground wire is connected through the L2 connection on the disconnect! You need to go through every box and device and verify the grounds are securely grounded and not switched.

We can't see the whole system and there may be circumstances not seen, but it appears it could be eliminated. One caution is that the HACR rating on the breaker is only applicable to AC equipment that the label says breakers are acceptable for protection. If the label only says "Maximum fuse size" the a fused disconnect is also required.

Comment: I'll verify when I'm home again. But this is a dedicated circuit from the main panel to this box. The hots and ground are basically one for one on each side. There are no other devices in this path.

Comment: To follow up, as I said earlier, this is a dedicated circuit. Ground is on L2 and traces all the way back to the main panel. No other devices are on this circuit. There are no fuses, just a 50amp breaker. I see no other issue here.

Comment: I would remove it, you  haven't disclosed any reason that it is needed. The splice needs still needs to be accessible. Looks like #6 wire, the box must be at least 25 in³, I would use a square 4 11/16" box. If you plan on covering with drywall you can use a single gang mud ring with a small cover.